# read full message in email with gmail api

Tags: gmail-api, google-api-python-client

beacuse I am using in snippet I get a A short part of the message text.
I am want to change that for getting the full body of the message
how i can do it ?

```
def get_message_detail(service, message_id, format='raw', metadata_headers=[]):
    try:
        message_detail = service.users().messages().get(
            userId='me',
            id=message_id,
            format=format,
            metadataHeaders=metadata_headers
        ).execute()
        return message_detail
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return None
if email_messages!= None:
    for email_message in email_messages:
        messageId = email_message['threadId']
        messageSubject = '(No subject) ({0})'.format(messageId)

        messsageDetail = get_message_detail(
            gmail_service, email_message['id'], format='full',
            metadata_headers=['parts'])
        messageDetailPayload = messsageDetail.get('payload')
        #print(messageDetailPayload)

        for item in messageDetailPayload['headers']:
            if item['name'] == 'Subject':
                if item['value']:
                    messageSubject = '{0} ({1})'.format(item['value'],messageId)

                    email_data = messsageDetail['payload']['headers']
                    #print(email_data)
                    #print(messageSubject)
                    for values in email_data:
                        name = values['name']
                        if name == "From":
                            from_name = values['value']
                            get_detil_msg = messsageDetail['snippet']
                            print(get_detil_msg)
```

Comment: What are you getting now?

Comment: i am geting a short text from the email body

Comment: whats in get_message_detail?

Comment: def get_message_detail(service, message_id, format='raw', metadata_headers=[]):

    try:

        message_detail = service.users().messages().get(
            userId='me',
            id=message_id,
            format=format,
            metadataHeaders=metadata_headers
        ).execute()

        return message_detail

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return None

Comment: you should edit your question and add that code not add it as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

This will return the full mime message if thats what your looking for.

```
#   To install the Google client library for Python, run the following command:
#   pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib


from __future__ import print_function

import base64
import email
import json
import os.path

import google.auth.exceptions
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/']


def Authorize(credentials_file_path, token_file_path):
    """Shows basic usage of authorization"""
    try:
        credentials = None
        # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
        # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
        # time.
        if os.path.exists(token_file_path):
            try:
                credentials = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(token_file_path, SCOPES)
                credentials.refresh(Request())
            except google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError as error:
                # if refresh token fails, reset creds to none.
                credentials = None
                print(f'An refresh authorization error occurred: {error}')
        # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
        if not credentials or not credentials.valid:
            if credentials and credentials.expired and credentials.refresh_token:
                credentials.refresh(Request())
            else:
                flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                    credentials_file_path, SCOPES)
                credentials = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
            # Save the credentials for the next run
            with open(token_file_path, 'w') as token:
                token.write(credentials.to_json())
    except HttpError as error:
        # Todo handle error
        print(f'An authorization error occurred: {error}')

    return credentials


def ListMessages(credentials):

    try:
        # create a gmail service object
        service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

        # Call the Gmail v1 API
        results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me').execute()
        messages = results.get('messages', [])

        if not messages:
            print('No messages where found.')
            return
        print('Messages:')
        for message in messages:
            getMessage(credentials, message['id'])
    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from gmail API.
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')


def getMessage(credentials, message_id):
    # get a message
    try:
        service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

        # Call the Gmail v1 API, retrieve message data.
        message = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message_id, format='raw').execute()

        # Parse the raw message.
        mime_msg = email.message_from_bytes(base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message['raw']))

        print(mime_msg['from'])
        print(mime_msg['to'])
        print(mime_msg['subject'])

        print("----------------------------------------------------")
        # Find full message body
        message_main_type = mime_msg.get_content_maintype()
        if message_main_type == 'multipart':
            for part in mime_msg.get_payload():
                if part.get_content_maintype() == 'text':
                    print(part.get_payload())
        elif message_main_type == 'text':
            print(mime_msg.get_payload())
        print("----------------------------------------------------")

        # Message snippet only.
        # print('Message snippet: %s' % message['snippet'])
    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from gmail API.
        print(f'A message get error occurred: {error}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    creds = Authorize('C:\\YouTube\\dev\\credentials.json', "token.json")
    ListMessages(creds)
```

Full tutorial: [How to read gmail message body with python?](https://www.daimto.com/how-to-read-gmail-message-body-with-python/)

Comment: i get mistake 
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting in the website is write
Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential

Comment: did you pass the credentials to the method?  This method takes credentials and a message_id   If you wait a bit im in the process of turning this into a tutorial should be out later today.

Comment: yes i pass them.
its fail on line : 
   message

Comment: check the tutorial.  but i just uploaded my fill script